# Retrieve specific value from for loop

Tags: java, android

In my `MainActivity.java` I have a fragment called `HomeFragment.java` and, inside that, I have a fragment called `CardStackFragment.java`. Basically, in my `HomeFragment` I display the title of my app and it's slogan.

And inside `CardStackFragment`, I display 5 cards with different country images and their respective name.

GIF of the HomeFragment:

[image: Click here to see a gif of my HomeFragment]

This is the code that I use to retrieve the images and their respective name from Firebase Realtime database in my `CardStackFragment`:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    // Carrega o nó "paises" da Base de Dados //

    DatabaseReference countriesRef = mDatabase.child("paises");
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            List<String> urlList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> nomePaisList = new ArrayList<>();

            // Carrega o nome e a imagem de todos os países para as listas urlList e nomePaisList//
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                String url = ds.child("Imagem").getValue(String.class); // Carrega as imagens
                String nomePais = ds.child("Nome").getValue(String.class); // Carrega os nomes
                urlList.add(url); // Adiciona as imagens à lista
                nomePaisList.add(nomePais); // Adiciona os nomes à lista
            }
            // A variável recebe a quantidade de paises que foram carregados //
            int urlCount = urlList.size();
            // A variável recebe um número random do total de países //
            int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(urlCount);
            // Declara as listas random //
            List<String> randomUrlList = new ArrayList<>(); // Lista da imagem random
            List<String> randomNomePaisList = new ArrayList<>(); // Lista do nome random
            // Ciclo que vai do 0 até ao total de países //
            for (int i=0; i<=Constants.TOTAL_PAISES; i++)
            {
                randomUrlList.add(urlList.get(randomNumber)); // Guarda um valor ao calhas de um país
                randomNomePaisList.add(nomePaisList.get(randomNumber)); // Guarda o nome referente à imagem que foi sorteada





Picasso.with(getContext()).load(randomUrlList.get(i)).into(imgFotoPais); 
txtPaisNome.setText(randomNomePaisList.get(i));

imgFotoPais.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
     Intent intentIntro = new Intent(getActivity(), 
     CountryInfoActivity.class); 
     startActivity(intentIntro); 

     getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up_info, R.anim.nothing);
                    }
                });

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
```

This code works perfectly. It gets me random images of the countries and their rescpective name...
What I want to achieve is, when I click on a specific card, I get redirected to a new activity `CountryCardInfo.java` with an ImageView of the size os the activity with the photo of the respective country I have selected... My first ideia was to store the image string (which is retrieved in the code I've posted) in the SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences sp = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
                        editor = getSharedPreferences("CardPhotoInfo", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

editor.putString("photoCountryInfo", randomUrlList.get(i);
```

And then, in my `CountryCardInfo.java` retrieve that String and place it in my ImageView using `Picasso.with(this).load(imagemPais).fit().into(imgCountryInfoFoto);`. The problem is, the SharedPreferences will always store the last image (the last loop), so, even if I click in the first country card, what I get in my other activity is the last country card image.

How can I manage to save in Shared Preferences only the String of the image that I clicked?

Comment: I find it hard to understand the essence of your question. If everything is working with your code, apart from getting the correct number out of your for loop, a simpler example [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful

Comment: Also, where are you setting the shared preferences in your code? And  isn't your for loop missing a closing brace?

Comment: Sorry ahah It's kind of hard to explain it without being confusing...
No, it is not missing, I didn't CTRL+C/ CTRL+V perfectly ahah.
I put my SharedPreferences before the `Picasso` instruction in the **for loop**

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly, you're currently storing that setting, and then in the next loop cycle instantly overwrite it. Might be worth trying to do that only when the card is clicked instead. (In the onClick Listener)

Comment: But I can't declare `i` to be final so I can use it in the setOnClick method...

Comment: How about `final int temp_i = i;`? I'm not sure but I think that should work

Comment: Well, you solved my problem xD Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem :) I added my comments as an answer.
Btw, for future questions I really recommend trying to boil down the question to a very small example (MCVE). Usually when I do that, I find out the answer before even finishing posting the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you're storing the value in the for loop, and the next loop cycle instantly overwrites it until you reach the largest `i`.

To solve this issue, place the storing code within the onClickListener to have it only happen when neccessary. As you pointed out, this needs a final variable and you cannot denote the loop variable `i` as `final`. The easiest solution that comes to mind is to add

```
final int temp_i = i;
```

in the loop, before the onClickListener and move the storing of the value into the onClickListener.